# Compiling sub projects in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I have some sub-projects those I need to compile with sbt. The structure is like this:

```
main_project
 - sub_project1
 - sub_project2
 - sub_project3
```

Of course, they have the correct directory hierarchy (src-main-scala....). How do I compile all of them and each of them in particular?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See [Navigating projects interactively](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html#navigating-projects-interactively):

> At the sbt interactive prompt, type `projects` to list your projects and `project <projectname>` to select a current project. When you run a task like `compile`, it runs on the current project. So you don't necessarily have to compile the root project, you could compile only a subproject.

You can use [aggregate](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html#aggregation) to compile them all.

Answer (score 5):

Because the selected answer's linked documentation has changed, the answer isn't so clear anymore.

In the `build.sbt` of OP's `main_project`, to compile them together they will have to define an `aggregate`, as the [new(er) documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Multi-Project.html#Aggregation) links to:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(util, core)

lazy val util = (project in file("util"))

lazy val core = (project in file("core"))
```

And then running an `sbt compile` in the root project's directory will compile them all.

However, if you wish to compile one at a time, you can navigate your cmd line/terminal to the root project ( `main_project` here) and then run the following command:

`user:main_project$: sbt <project name> / compile`

to use the poster's example:

`user:main_project$: sbt sub_project1 / compile`

(if you are in the SBT terminal, then you can omit `sbt`)

Comment: Maybe helpful for someone: I had to drop the spaces, i.e. `sbt sub_project1/compile` instead of `sbt sub_project1 / compile`. Else sbt complains with `[error] Expected '/' (if selecting a project)` (among other errors).